# Access /etc/mysql/my.cnf using Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

How can I edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` if I use this docker-compose? I need to comment `bind-address` out to allow connections from all hosts.

https://github.com/indiehosters/piwik/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 6):

Access the docker container using it's ID

```
sudo docker exec -i -t 665b4a1e17b6 /bin/bash
```

Navigate to /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
  cd /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Install Nano text editor

```
apt-get install nano
```

Export environment variable

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Edit your file

```
nano my.cnf
```

Comment: This will only work if the container runs as root.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to edit files inside a container. You can override the file with `--volume`, but you should create a new container which you customize to fit your needs. Build on the container you are using like this:

```
FROM foo/bar:1.0
USER root
RUN sed -i -e "/^bind-address/d" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
USER mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing files in a container *during development* is a very common use-case.

I would recommend taking a look at bind-mount [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) — mount a local project directory/file inside your Docker container at runtime.

```yaml
# Note this is ONLY for the local Docker environment.
# It has nothing to do with deployments.

version: "3.8"
services:

  # Local mock database.
  database:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0
    restart: always
    container_name: database
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      # Files
      - ./db/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf:ro
      # Dirs
      - ./db/datadir/:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./db/initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
```

In your local project directory, you have a subdirectory called `db/` with a file called `my.cnf` (and optionally other volume mounts for data).

If the Docker image *already* has a file at `/etc/my.cnf`, mounting this way will *overlay* the one from your local filesystem *over* the built-in one, so that the container only sees the one from your local filesystem. Without the volume mount, it will only see the one that's baked-in.